# Cannot spawnModel from MATLAB

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to do connection between MATLAB and Gazebo and generate Gazebo model from MATLAB. I follow the instruction in [add-build-and-remove-objects-in-gazebo](https://www.mathworks.com/help/robotics/examples/add-build-and-remove-objects-in-gazebo.html), and the following commands work successfully.

```
rosinit(ipaddress)
gazebo = ExampleHelperGazeboCommunicator;
ball = ExampleHelperGazeboModel('Ball') 
spherelink = addLink(ball,'sphere',1,'color',[0 0 1 1])
```

But when I run the next command `spawnModel(gazebo,ball,[8.5,0,1])`, the errors show up in MATLAB command window:

```
Error using ExampleHelperGazeboCommunicator/startModelServices (line 334)
Failed to create a /gazebo/get_model_state service client.

Error in ExampleHelperGazeboCommunicator/spawnModel (line 290)
            startModelServices(obj);

[ERROR] ServiceClientHandshakeHandler - Service client handshake failed: client wants service 
/gazebo/get_model_state to have md5sum af0f702011820738976b120226dc9d96, but it has 
4c515e936d3319c9610c559c60bfc3d4. Dropping connection.
```

The error shown in ubuntu terminal is

```
[ERROR] ServiceClientHandshakeHandler - Service client handshake failed: client wants service 
/gazebo/get_model_state to have md5sum af0f702011820738976b120226dc9d96, but it has 
4c515e936d3319c9610c559c60bfc3d4. Dropping connection.
```

I use matlab 2018b, Robotics System Toolbox2.1 on win10, and Ubuntu18.04, ROS melodic, gazebo9 in virtualbox, which are all newest version. Does anyone know how to solve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20707/cannot-spawnmodel-from-matlab/) by [jwchang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5575/jwchang/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Solution is here [Update MATLAB's ROS Messages](https://visionlab.uncc.edu/dokuwiki/range-only_slam_from_matlab_using_ros_and_the_gazebo_simulator)

Update rosjava_messages.jar and then spawn models successfully.

---

Originally posted by [jwchang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5575/jwchang/) with karma: 15 on 2018-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0